# Validate form depending on another field

Tags: django-forms, django-validation

I have this form:

```
class NetworkInput(forms.Form):          
    IP = forms.GenericIPAddressField()     
    Netmask = forms.IntegerField()
```

The users should be able to enter an IPv4 or an IPv6 address.
Depending of the IP version the validation of Netmask should look like this:

```
import ipcalc
IP = ipcalc.IP(IP)
if IP.version() == 4:
    if Netmask > 29:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not big enough' % value)
else:
    if Netmask > 125:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not big enough' % value)
```

But I don't know how to access the variable IP when validating the Netmask.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the django docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

create a clean() method that does the combined validation, e.g

```
def clean(self):
    IP = self.cleaned_data['IP']
    Netmask = self.cleaned_data['Netmask']
    IP = ipcalc.IP(IP)
    if IP.version() == 4:
        if Netmask > 29:
            raise ValidationError(u'%s is not big enough' % value)
    else:
        if Netmask > 125:
            raise ValidationError(u'%s is not big enough' % value)
```

Comment: That looks better. But you forgot to return the data. :)
Anyway, if I give him now not a valid IPv4/6 address I end up in a KeyError?